# ¿Por qué me de un Error al recuperar el listado del directorio ftp Centos?

Tags: ftp, centos, centos7, ftpclient, vsftp

Acabo de configurar mi usuario ftp con su respectivo directorio y contraseña de acceso, pero cuando intento acceder usando filezilla me muestra el siguiente error, intente configurar el gestor de sitios, pero el error sigue siendo el mismo.

> Estado:   Conectando a 31.220.60.211:21...
> Estado: Conexión establecida, esperando el mensaje de bienvenida...
> Estado: Servidor no seguro, no soporta FTP sobre TLS.
> Estado: Registrado en
> Estado: Recuperando el listado del directorio...
> Comando:    PWD
> Respuesta:  257 "/"
> Comando:    TYPE I
> Respuesta:  200 Switching to Binary mode.
> Comando:    PASV
> Respuesta:  227 Entering Passive Mode (31,220,60,211,250,111).
> Comando:    LIST
> Error:  La conexión superó el tiempo de espera después de 20 segundos de inactividad
> Error:  Error al recuperar el listado del directorio

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Puedes facilitar la configuración del servicio FTP del servidor?